# Populate HTML Table with MySQL Table Data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm really new to HTML/PHP and I want to build a simple website that returns the data from my MySQL database in form of a table..

My code looks like this for now:

```
<?php
  $server = mysql_connect("server", "username", "password"); 
  $db = mysql_select_db("ni354077_2sql1", $server); 
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Jobs"); 
?>

         <table>
            <tr>
                <td>AuftragsID</td>
                <td>Startort</td>
                <td>Zielort</td>
                <td>Gewicht</td>
                <td>Fracht</td>
            </tr>

            <?php
               while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                   echo "<tr>";
                   echo "<td>".$row[AuftragsID]."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$row[Startort]."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$row[Zielort]."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$row[Gewicht]."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$row[Fracht]."</td>";
                   echo "</tr>";
               }

            ?>
        </table>
```

However it doesn't seem to be working properly. My table is full of "echo (..)" here is a Picutre of what it looks like: 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eGCg.png]

Am I missing something ? I'm coming from C# WinForms and am confused with that.

Comment: Looks like you have missed to close `"` somewhere before this code

Comment: you missed quotes around to the values, Please check  my answer.thanks

Answer (score 5):

use this u have missed single quotes around php values, put like below

```
          <?php
               while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {?>
                   <tr>
                   <td><?php echo $row['AuftragsID'];?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $row['Startort'];?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $row['Zielort'];?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $row['Gewicht'];?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $row['Fracht'];?></td>
                   </tr>
              <?php  } ?>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what changes you have done to make it correct??

Comment: Semi-works now. My table looks fine now but it's empty. I've already checked for misspellings in my Database but that seems to be alright

Comment: @TobiasKarl so print your query and run in phpmyadmin and check results are coming or not and and use 'or die(mysql_error)'

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you mentioned that you're new to PHP.

According to PHP mYSQL Documentation.

> **Warning** This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be
>   removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension
>   should be used.

In other words. mySql will not be available and you better start using mySqli or PDO (PHP DATA OBJECTS).

MYSQLI:  http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

The error you're getting because you're getting the key of array without quotes

Right Syntax:

```
$arrName['keyName'];
```

So you're solution will be like this

```
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['AuftragsID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Startort'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Zielort'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Gewicht'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Fracht'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This Code:
<?php
  $server = mysql_connect("server", "username", "password"); 
  $db = mysql_select_db("ni354077_2sql1", $server); 
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Jobs"); 
?>

         <table>
            <tr>
                <td>AuftragsID</td>
                <td>Startort</td>
                <td>Zielort</td>
                <td>Gewicht</td>
                <td>Fracht</td>
            </tr>

            <?php
               while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
?>
                  <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row[AuftragsID]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row[Startort]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row[Zielort]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row[Gewicht]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row[Fracht]; ?></td>
            </tr>
    <?php
               }

            ?>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

first use table row then use the loop inside PHP then populate your table with the data from the database

```
    <tr>
   <?php
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
     {
   ?>
   <td><?php echo $row["AuftragsID"]?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row["Startort"] ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row[Zielort]?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row[Gewicht]?></td>
   <td> <?php echo $row[Fracht]?></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Please format your code appropriately. It will be much easier to read and understand.

Answer (score -1):

change the loop to

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

               echo "<tr>";
               echo "<td>".$row['AuftragsID']."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$row['Startort']."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$row['Zielort']."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$row['Gewicht']."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$row['Fracht']."</td>";
               echo "</tr>";
           }
```

Comment: Add quotes to the field names